# How can I find the difference in population by year and zip code using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with ACS data and I have used the dplyr package to filter my data to this. However, I am trying to use mutate within dplyr to find the increase and decrease in total population from 2013 to 2016 based on zip code. for example I want to create a new column that finds for zip 43001 what was the difference in total population from 2013 to 2016

My input:

```
filterdacs_D1 <- mutate(filename,difference1 =$zip$total_population[total_population]-$zip$total_population2017)
```

But this is incorrect as I want the difference between 2016 and 2014 for each zip code.

The dataframe:

```
     Year        Zip      Total_Population Median_Income             City    
1    2013 ZCTA5 43001             2475         87333               Alexandria    OH
2    2013 ZCTA5 43002             2753         83873                  Amlin           OH
3    2014 ZCTA5 43003             2366         46691                 Ashley         OH
4    2014 ZCTA5 43001            24625         70809              Blacklick        OH
5    2014 ZCTA5 43005              155         43810            Bladensburg    OH
6    2015 ZCTA5 43006              705         45673             Brinkhaven    OH
7    2015 ZCTA5 43001             2430         28422           Buckeye Lake    OH
8    2016 ZCTA5 43009             2036         62188                  Cable    OH
9    2016 ZCTA5 43010              386         34625                Catawba    OH
10   2016 ZCTA5 43001             7733        66548             Centerburg    OH
```

How do I go about this in R?

Comment: In your code, you've referred to a few things that don't match the data you're showing: your population column is named "Total_Population", not "population", and you misspelled "population" once. It also doesn't make sense that you have `$zip$population`—I'm not sure what `$zip` should be doing there. The easiest way is probably to just use `tidyr::spread` to make columns for each year

Comment: @camille Thank you I have edited the above

Comment: Still not right. R is case sensitive, so `total_population != Total_Population`. Take a look at `group_by`, but without a real [mcve] we can't do much more.

Comment: @camille if i make columns for each year how do I factor in the zip codes? because I am looking for data based on zip code like for example Which 10 zip codes experienced the greatest decrease in total population from 2016 to 2013

Answer (score 2):

There is plenty of help out there for a problem like this but I would probably attack it in way like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

zips <- tibble::tribble(
    ~Year,          ~Zip, ~Total_Population, ~Median_Income,                 ~City,
     2013, "ZCTA5 43001",              2475,          87333,    "Alexandria    OH",
     2013, "ZCTA5 43002",              2753,          83873,  "Amlin           OH",
     2014, "ZCTA5 43003",              2366,          46691,   "Ashley         OH",
     2014, "ZCTA5 43001",             24625,          70809, "Blacklick        OH",
     2014, "ZCTA5 43005",               155,          43810,   "Bladensburg    OH",
     2015, "ZCTA5 43006",               705,          45673,    "Brinkhaven    OH",
     2015, "ZCTA5 43001",              2430,          28422,  "Buckeye Lake    OH",
     2016, "ZCTA5 43009",              2036,          62188,         "Cable    OH",
     2016, "ZCTA5 43010",               386,          34625,       "Catawba    OH",
     2016, "ZCTA5 43001",              7733,          66548,    "Centerburg    OH"
    )

diff <-  zips %>% dplyr::filter(Year %in% c(2013,2016)) %>% 
    spread(Year,Total_Population) %>% group_by(Zip) %>%
    summarise(`Total2013` = sum(`2013`, na.rm = TRUE),
              `Total2016` = sum(`2016`, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    mutate(Difference = Total2013- Total2016)

diff
```

You have to break your problem down into smaller bites instead of trying to think there is just one function that can do what you are looking for.

Comment: I am new to R. Thank you for your insight. Also, I tried to use zips <- tibble::tribble(dataframe) for my entire data frame but I  got an error Error: Expected at least one column name; e.g. `~name`
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

Comment: If you are trying to put your original dataframe into tibble::tribble() it will not work. Just copy everything after the tible::tribble() statement and run it on the original dataframe.

Comment: Correct. But the issue I am facing is dataset has 50 zip codes and not all data will display at once in the console so I am unable to paste all the data and do the above with tibble(). I could filter and use 10 zip codes each time but want to know if there is a more efficient way of wrangling and manipulating the data with such large dataframes

Comment: If you already have your data in the form of a dataframe you can skip the tribble part and go from here ```diff <-  your_data_frame %>% dplyr::filter(Year %in% c(2013,2016)) %>% 
    spread(Year,Total_Population) %>% group_by(Zip) %>%
    summarise(`Total2013` = sum(`2013`, na.rm = TRUE),
              `Total2016` = sum(`2016`, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
    mutate(Difference = Total2013- Total2016)

diff ```